# Validar URL de perfil do facebook

Tags: php, regex

Como posso validar uma URL de perfil do facebook e pegar o id do usuário?
Exemplos:

> http://www.facebook.com/walterwhite
>   http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxx

E as outras variações:

```
htttps://facebook
www.facebook
```

E pegar o valor do id, dos exemplos, seriam:

> walterwhite  e xxxxx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
function fbUser( $url ) {
    preg_match('~^https?://(www.)?facebook.com/(profile\.php\?id=)?(.*)~',$url,$matches);
    return $matches[3];
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/gen1TF)**.

Entendendo a RegEx:

```
~^https?://(www.)?facebook.com/(profile\.php\?id=)?(.*)~   Essa é a RegEx completa.
~                                                      ~   Delimitadores de começo e fim
 ^                                                         Indica o começo da linha
      s?   (www.)?             (profile\.php\?id=)?        Campos opcionais
  http  ://       facebook.com/                            Caracteres fixos (obrigatórios)
                                                   (.*)    retornamos este valor
```

Segue uma versão ainda mais robusta, que separa os parâmetros da *query string* e ignora `?` e `/` nos URLs com nome:

```
function fbUser( $url ) {
   $rgx='~^https?://(www\.)?facebook.com/(?|profile\.php\?(?:.*&)*id=([^&]*)|([^/\?]*))~';
   if( preg_match( $rgx, $url, $matches ) ) return $matches[2];
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/8C6Fc3)**.

<sub><sup>Esta solução usou a sugestão do nosso mestre em RegEx, [@GuilhermeLautert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14213/), de usar *branch reset* (grupos alternativos), com a sintaxe (?| )</sup></sub>

Comment: Lembre que qualquer coisa você pode usar o `(?|)` para forçar um grupo a poder te mais de um  resultado :D

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 agora acho que ficou bem legal: http://ideone.com/8C6Fc3

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente usando [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) e [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php) da para fazer com facilidade.

Retorna o `ID` ou `null` caso não seja a url do facebook ou não consiga detectar o id.

```
function getFbId($url){
    $fbId = null;
    $info = parse_url($url);

    if( isset($info['host']) && preg_match('/facebook\.com/', $info['host']) ){
        if(isset($info['query'])){
            $qs = parse_str($info['query'], $params);
            if( isset($params['id']) ){
                //pega o id aqui $params['id']
                $fbId = $params['id'];
            }
        }else if( isset($info['path']) ){
            $path = str_replace('/', '', $info['path']);
            //precisa ajustar essa expressao, não lembro exatamente se isso tudo é permitido ou falta algo
            if(preg_match('/\.php/', $path)==0){
                if( preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9]|\.|_)+/', $path)>0 ){
                    $fbId = $path;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $fbId;
}

var_dump(getFbId('http://www.facebook.com/walterwhite'));
var_dump(getFbId('http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxx'));
```

Confesso que não é a função mais bonita do mundo mas resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Retornar o id de usuário tem uma certa dificuldade, se for o nome público a forma acima vai te solucionar caso tenha o input da url. Caso precise do ID real do usuário sugiro utilizar a dom e manipular a class de imagem de profile: "profilePicThumb" e pegar a string entre "fbid=" e "&set". Esse é o id utilizado pelo facebook, pra fins de campanha de Ads não resulturá em nada, já que o face excluiu a opção de subir bases baseadas em Id. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não seria pra usar nenhuma API, só pra pegar o id do perfil mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Aí vai tudo em uma única REGEX, terminei agora:

```
//Retirar possíveis espaços na digitação
    $odominioface = preg_replace('/([\s]+)/i', '', $_POST['link_do_facebook_profile']);
    preg_match('/^(http(?:s)?[\:][\/][\/](?:www[\.])?facebook[\.]com[\/])(?:([a-z0-9\-\_]+)|(?:profile[\.]php[\?]id[\=]([0-9]{15})))$/i', $odominioface, $resultadodominioface);

if((isset($resultadodominioface[1]) == true) and ($resultadodominioface[1] != null)){

if((isset($resultadodominioface[2]) == true) and ($resultadodominioface[2] != null)){

echo "Puts grilla bicho eu achei o nome do perfil na URL! O nome é: ".$resultadodominioface[2]."<br />";

} elseif((isset($resultadodominioface[3]) == true) and ($resultadodominioface[3] != null)){

echo "Não encontrei o nome do perfil, mas pelo menos achei o id! O id é: ".$resultadodominioface[3]."<br />";

} else{
echo "Que mer* bicho! Não encontrei nada!<br />";
}

}
```

AS VARIÁVEIS:

`$resultadodominioface[1] ->` Retorna o nome do domínio, se não nouver essa tudo o mais já é desconsiderado no script

`$resultadodominioface[2] ->` O nome do cara na URL, não é obrigatório pois o script não importa pois ele analiza a existencia dele ou não.

`$resultadodominioface[3] ->` O id do cara

No caso eu avalei a variável ($resultadodominioface[1]), pois se não houver um domínio válido todo o resto será inválido, pois tudo depende dela. Neste caso a expressão regular permite:

http://facebook.com/fulano
OU
https://facebook.com/fulano

http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=123789123456777
OU
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=123789123456777

http://www.facebook.com/fulano OU https://www.facebook.com/fulano

http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123789123456777
OU
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123789123456777

Fiz agora e testei bastante! Obrigado! Não preciso do script mas se eu precisar, graças a ti, já está pronto! Thanks!